# How can I set the ClientId and Authority dynamically for single sign on using OpenIdConnect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, single-sign-on, owin

We have multiple tenants, and they use different authorities (their own, not just standard providers). While I know how to dynamically set the clientId and secret, I can't figure out how to set the authority. It is set once, during startup, and afterward it cannot be changed (or so it seems).

Since we have a lot of tenants, we don't want to register all at startup, and we also don't want to require a restart when tenants are added.

ClientId and authorities set based on tenant selection instead of owin startup.cs class.

Any suggestions how I can go about this?

Below code, I used in OwinStartup.cs class:

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        
        // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
        Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
        
        // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
        
        // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
        // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
        // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false // This is a simplification
        },
        
        // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync
        }
    });
}
```

I want to move above code from OwinStartup.cs class to Controller Action method.

Answer (score -1):

In the RedirectToIdentityProvider notification you can override the authority, issuer and metadata address. You will need to set a default authority in the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions though.

```
...
Authority = $"{yourDefaultAuthority}"
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
   RedirectToIdentityProvider = n => 
   {
      n.Options.Authority = $"{yourAuthorityHere}";
      n.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = $"{yourAuthorityHere}/connect/authorize";
      n.Options.MetadataAddress = $"{yourAuthorityHere}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
   }
}
```